# android gps is not showing right lan and lon

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-gps

Below is my code and when I am near to this

> (distance is less than 100 meter from my current  location)
>   9.443469,76.540650

gps location i need to vibrate my phone , but when i reach there it is not vibrating and it is showing wrong lan and lon. 
What is wrong in my code?

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import io.nlopez.smartlocation.OnLocationUpdatedListener;
import io.nlopez.smartlocation.SmartLocation;
import io.nlopez.smartlocation.location.config.LocationAccuracy;
import io.nlopez.smartlocation.location.config.LocationParams;

public class OfferLocator extends Service {
    SmartLocation mSmartLocation;
    LocationParams locationParam = null;
    double l2 = 9.443469, lo2 = 76.540650, lan = 0, lon = 0;
    boolean running = false;
    double prelan = 0, prelon = 0;
    MyLocationListener locationListener;
    int ct = 0;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    private void info() {
        if (locationManager == null) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        if (locationListener == null) {
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, locationListener);

        Log.i("OfferLocator_info","info called "+ct+" times  lan lon "+lan+","+lon);
        ct++;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                info();
            }
        },10000);
        try {
           if(locationParam==null) locationParam = new LocationParams.Builder().setAccuracy(LocationAccuracy.HIGH).build();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("OfferLocatorv2","error2 :"+e.getMessage()+"");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("myLog", "Service: onCreate");
        try {
            locationParam = new LocationParams.Builder().setAccuracy(LocationAccuracy.HIGH).build();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("OfferLocatorv2","error2 :"+e.getMessage()+"");
        }
        info();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("myLog", "Service: onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.d("myLog", "Service: onTaskRemoved");

        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
            Intent restart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
            restart.setPackage(getPackageName());
            startService(restart);
        }

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OfferLocator.class));
        } else {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OfferLocator.class));
        }
        Log.d("myLog", "Service: onDestroy");
        // unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        String TAG="newloc";
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            //  editLocation.setText("");
            // pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            double l2 = 9.443469, lo2 = 76.540650;
            float[] results = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween( loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(),l2,lo2, results);
            if (results[0]<100) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"vibrate please "+results[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                    } else {
                        //deprecated in API 26
                        v.vibrate(1500);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("OfferLocatorv2","error4 :"+e.getMessage()+"");
                }
            } else {
                if (results[0]>500) {
                    try {
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                        } else {
                        //deprecated in API 26
                            v.vibrate(1500);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.i("OfferLocatorv2","error4 :"+e.getMessage()+"");
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"my current location is "+results[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
            Log.v(TAG, longitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
            Log.v(TAG, latitude);

            /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
            String cityName = null;
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                        loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: " + cityName;
            // editLocation.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have taken the coordinates from google map they can be slightly different from those obtained from the same position through the MapsActivity. Try to take the coordinates of the point where you want the phone to vibrate through another application with a MapsActivity that simply give you with the coordinates of your position.